# Order a VARCHAR column numerically

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Current SQL: `SELECT code FROM myTable ORDER BY code ASC`

`code`
`---`
`11`
`113`
`12`
`13A`

This is the current order I have of a MySQL table.

I want the order to be A-Z, 1-10 however, numerically, like this:

`code`
`---`
`11`
`12`
`13A`
`113`

The reason I cannot achieve this effect in the first place is because the code column is varchar and not int. However as shown in the example, some codes have a letter prepended to them so I cannot change this to integer.

How can I get around this problem without changing the data type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use silent conversion.  Just add 0:

```
order by code + 0
```

In practice, you might want:

```
order by code + 0, code
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Just out of interest, if one wanted to do 1-10 then A-Z with the same effect, how could I do that?

Comment: Apparently (and a bit surprising to me) this seems to work, but out of curiosity, what happens to the A in 13A when MySQL does silent conversion? How is it possible to convert it to an integer?

Comment: @jskidd3 . . . MySQL does silent conversion of strings in an arithmetic context.  That means that it ignores errors and converts the string up to the first non-numeric character.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, sorting by number first and alpha after (if the same number):

```
select * from myTable
order by cast(replace(code,'[0-9]+','') as unsigned), code
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53af0/1)

Comment: How could I alter this so that it order 1-10 and then A-Z?

Comment: @jskidd3 Just add the `code` as the second sort parameter. I've updated the query.